# selenium won't accept my variable value

Tags: python, selenium

this is either python or selenium that's is either not incrementing the value of the variable "scraped_pages" or won't recognize it's value.

```
page_num = raw_input("How any page?: ")
urls_list = []
scraped_pages = 0
while scraped_pages <= page_num:
    for li in list_items:
        for a in li.find_all('a', href=True):
            url = a['href']
            if slicer(url,'http'):
                url1 = slicer(url,'http')
                urls_list.append(url1)
            elif slicer(url,'www'):
                urls1 = slicer(url,'www')
                urls_list.append(urls1)
            else:
                pass
    print urls_list         
    scraped_pages +=1
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div[4]/div[9]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[5]/div/span[1]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[12]").click()
```

It scrapes only 2 pages and then I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "google page click.py", line 46, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div[4]/div[9]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[5]/div/span[1]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[12]").click()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 75, in click
```

Comment: Did you set an implicit/explicit wait?

Comment: I've tried implicit waits, I didn't do an explicit becuase it's not waiting for any elements on the page it needs to wait for the content to be scraped.

Comment: add more details like web url  html code etc.

Comment: I just tried an implicit wait and it's done the same thing, keeps going past the value of "page_nums".

Comment: Why not try--  page_num = int(raw_input("How any page?: "))